# javascript OOP concept issue

Tags: javascript

i have this simple code :

```
// You can use either PIXI.WebGLRenderer or PIXI.CanvasRenderer
  var renderer;
  var stage;
  var bunnyTexture;
  var bunny;
  var Game= {};
 Game.Init = function() { };
 Game.Init.prototype={
    init:function(){
         renderer= new PIXI.WebGLRenderer(800, 600);
         document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
        stage= new PIXI.Stage;
        bunnyTexture= PIXI.Texture.fromImage("img/ninja.png");
        bunny= new PIXI.Sprite(bunnyTexture);
        bunny.position.x = 400;
         bunny.position.y = 300;
       stage.addChild(bunny);

 },
  animate:function(){
       bunny.rotation += 0.01;
       renderer.render(stage);
       requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);

  }
}
    requestAnimationFrame(Game.Init.animate);
```

i am calling the function like this :

```
   window.onload = function () { Game.Init(); };
```

a javascript error saying : `Argument 1 of Window.requestAnimationFrame is not an object.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Game.Init` is a constructor function you should initialize object properly with `new` keyword:

```
new Game.Init();
```

Otherwise the context will be global object `Window` and `this.animate` is `undefined`. To help you to detect such a problems I would recommend to `use strict` mode, which would have failed with error on the very early steps.

Comment: i am still getting the same error can u give me an example of how can i fix my error please